# Add Horizontal line in center of A4 size page using Laravel Dompdf

Tags: html, laravel-5, printing, dompdf

I am working on invoice management system, where I need to print 2 copy of invoice (Original and Duplicate)in single A4 page to just reuse the page.

I am using Laravel 5.6 and [laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf).

I need something like this
[image: paper center lin]
so that folding a page to center/half of page will make 2 copies without losing any content in print.

I am parsing Laravel blade view file. I need such a solution that it uses css only.

Comment: Have to ask, are you certain that the two invoices will perfectly fit on an A4 every time? Placing a line at the center of the page should be trivial (you could do this via CSS or Canvas methods). But ensuring your content does not flow over that line would be less so unless you have a fairly static format.

Comment: @BrianS It will be always 8 rows in table, so I am sure it will never overflow